# how to get only items has avg rate equal value in one query laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

i want get only items has avg rate equal [3,5] // Example

when write in model

```
public function rate()
{
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Rate', 'fk_service')->avg('rate');
}
```

get error Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on string

when remove "->avg(rate)" 
get all data but i want only average rate

when write in model

```
public function rate()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Rate', 'fk_service');
}
```

// and in controller

```
$engravings = Engraving::where('engravings.status', 1);
if(!empty($request->rate)){
    $engravings->whereHas('rate', function($query) use ($request){
        // Code use WhereIn How To do it
    });
}

$engravings = $engravings->get();
```

Comment: in post lost '' in avg('rate') 

public function rate()
{
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Rate', 'fk_service')->avg('rate');
}

Comment: *"how to get only items has avg rate equal value in one query laravel?"* in (My)SQL language that would require a simple filter condition something like... `SELECT * FROM table WHERE rate = (SELECT AVG(rate) FROM table)` also assuming i interpreted the question correctly... Hard to give a more solid answer without knowing table structure, data and result which you are after.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

// Code use WhereIn How To do it

```
$query->whereIn('rate', [3,5]);
```

Comment: if use in model
public function rate()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Rate', 'fk_service');
}

// not work 
if use 
public function rate()
{
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Rate', 'fk_service')->avg('rate');
}

// get error Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on string